# How can I retrieve the latest donation information in real-time from Streamlabs API using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve the latest donation information from Streamlabs API using Python, and I want to do this in real-time. To achieve this, I'm using an access token that I obtained using the authorization code flow, and I'm setting the scope to donation.read in my API request.

However, I keep getting unauthorized errors, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I checked my API key and made sure that the scope parameter is correct, but I'm still getting the same error.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Is there a specific way to retrieve real-time donation information from Streamlabs API?

Here are some details about my setup:

Programming language: Python
API request method: GET
API endpoint: https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/socket/token
Authorization method: Bearer Token
Scope parameter: donation.read

```
import requests

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
redirect_uri = ""
scope = "donations.read"
state = "123456"

auth_url = f"https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&state={state}"

# Get authorization code
print(f"Open this URL to get authorization code: {auth_url}")
auth_code = input("Enter authorization code: ")

# Exchange authorization code for access token
token_url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/token"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

data = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "code": auth_code
}

response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
    print("Access token:", access_token)
else:
    print(f"Access token could not be retrieved. Error code: {response.status_code}, Error message: {response.json()['message']}")

# Get socket token
socket_url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/socket/token"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(socket_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    socket_token = response.json()["socket_token"]
    print("Socket token:", socket_token)

    # Test socket token
    test_url = "https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=" + socket_token
    test_response = requests.get(test_url)

    if test_response.status_code == 200:
        print("Socket token is valid.")
    else:
        print(f"Socket token is invalid. Error code: {test_response.status_code}, Error message: {test_response.text}")
else:
    print(f"Socket token could not be retrieved. Error code: {response.status_code}, Error message: {response.json()['message']}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Streamlabs' WebSocket API to get the real-time donation information but in your code it is a GET request to the WebSocket endpoint, those are not the same as HTTP request.

You should install the websocket library `pip install websocket-client` then change your code to retrieve it properly:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    data = json.loads(message)
    if data['type'] == 'donation':
        print("New donation:", data)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("Error:", error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection closed")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Connected to Streamlabs WebSocket")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=" + socket_token,
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: you are f... awesome man :D Thank you so much